# C# 'Internal error retrieving local value' while trying to get button value for method

Tags: c#

I'm working on 'HangMan' game. And while debugging when i try to get the value of a button for a method that checks if that value matches one letter of the chosen word i see this error in the debugger window and the var btn inside the CheckLetter_Click wont get any value at all: 'Internal error retrieving local value'.

What could be the problam with this?

```
 private void CheckLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        Mng.CheckLetter(btn);
    }
```

The CheckLetter method from the Game Manager class:

```
TextBlock[] txtBlkArr = { tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4, tb5, tb6 };

 public bool CheckLetter(Button btn)
    {
        foreach (var c in txtBlkArr)
        {
            if (btn.Content == c)
            {
                c.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                //if (txtBlkArr[txtBlkArr.Length - 1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible)
                //{
                //    GameWon();
                //}

            }
            else
            {
                //StartHanging();
                WrongCounter++;
                btn.IsEnabled = false;
                //txtBlkUsedLetters += txtBlkArr[i];
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What error? You have not added it. Also, you must add the code of the `Mng` class.

Comment: What do you mean "try to get the value of a button"? Is it the line where you cast sender as button?

Comment: @Gusman I've writen the error in the question title. this is the error: 'Internal error retrieving local value'

Comment: @RufusL I've assinged several buttons to the event i put here and that event supposed to send the value of the clicked button to the CheckLetter method to check the value against one textblock which contains one letter

Comment: I assume this is WPF?

Comment: Just a description in the title isn't enough, add the complete exception details including error code and the line which caused the exception. ANd add the missing code.

Comment: @TiesonT. No this is WINRT Win8 GUI

Comment: @Gusman Ok i'm sorry, for future reference i will add the needed deatails in advance next time.  for this question are those enough?

Comment: Please edit this question with all the details. Not everyone will read through all the comments. Think of future users who have a similar problem and are looking for a question that matches their scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *CheckLetter* method the **c** variable is of type **TextBlock**, you are trying to compare its value with the value of **btn.Content** which is of type **object** in this line of code:

```
if (btn.Content == c)
```

That's the root of the problem. You need to cast comparing values to the same type (string or char in your case), like this:

```
if ((btn.Content as string) == c.Text)
```

Comment: I guess that solves me a problam i would have faced later on, so thank you for that!  But my current problam for which i have asked this question was about the 'btn' variable. It wont recognize any value of a button that i click on and when i debbug my program i see the error message i posted in the question.